# Render and serve HTML file with CSS/JS from server disk to Client Browser

Tags: html, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, react-admin

I'm stuck with an issue which ,in simple terms, is to **find a way to securely render and serve HTML files (along with CSS, JS) from local disk in server to the web app running in the client browser.**

**APPLICATIONS**

1. Front end Web app is created using React JS (react-admin to be exact).
2. The back end that handles the Rest API requests is setup using Net core 3.1
3. Both applications are hosted in IIS in a Windows server (as application service inside default website in IIS).

**CONSTRAINTS**

1. The hosting of the applications has to happen only inside the IIS in windows server. (Other options are also welcome)
2. Back end / Front end can be in any language as we desire. (preferably dot net core since i'm using c# for last 10 years)

**TECHNICAL DETAILS**

I'm working on developing a solution to host point cloud viewer (Potree, an opensource project which is developed using three-js). This is a standalone process. A desktop based C++ converter is provided by the Potree which converts the inputs to a webpage (with  html, css, js) (**LETS CALL THIS AS TARGET FILES**). We can host this webpage in any server to be viewed by external parties.

**CURRENT STATUS**

1. **Working:** The target files are hosted in IIS server as an application and it can be accessed without any issue. (image can be seen below).
2. **Working:** The react js web app is built and the dist files are hosted in IIS server and it can also be accessed without any issue.

Above two steps confirm that both the built applications work well as they can be hosted individually and can also be accessed from other computers.

[image]

**FEATURE THAT I'M STUCK WITH**

1. The target files are meant for different users. So, this has to be served after validating through an API request.
2. Current setup is such that when user clicks a link in the react application, it makes an REST Api call which is handled by the back end dotnet core app (there could be other better ways to serve the html files to the front end web app).
3. I tried several ways to serve HTML file. 
   Option 1: Use StaticFiles (in startup). I'm trying to read the html file from local and then render it inside a noidea.cshtml file using `@Html.Raw(Model.SomePropertyName)`

   ```
       // GET: /<controller>/
   public IActionResult noidea()
   {
       try
       {
           var newmodel = new noideaModel();
           var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("./acl-i/acl-i.html");
           newmodel._html = string.Join("", file);
           return View(newmodel);

           //return View();
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           throw;
       }
   }
   ```

   }

This option works partially fine but the problem is that since I have put the files inside a static folder (configured in startup) users can easily change the URL and access other files present there.

[image]

So, i tried to do with option 2 which is to just read the contents of the html file from local disk and serve it as content result.:

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet, Route("viewer")]
    public IActionResult getViewer()
    {
        //For serving single static html file.
        var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("./acl-i/acl-i.html");
        var item = string.Join("", file);

        return new ContentResult
        {
            ContentType = "text/html",
            StatusCode = (int)StatusCodes.Status200OK,
            Content = item
        };
    }
```

The success point here is, I'm able to properly authenticate and users cannot change the URL since the api end point serves the file.
Problem is that i just serves only the HTMl and the linked css, js are not recognized by the client browser. Below image shows the issue. The js and CSS are also being searched in the same api end point.

[image]

**QUESTION:**

I'm new to react js and web front end development. I mostly work with Xamarin, C#/WPF/XML for desktop apps, and develop Web API end points for CRUD applications. So, I"m totally stuck here. No idea how to sort out the problem.

1. I'm looking for solving the current issue.
2. Or to find an elegant easy way to solve the issue (I also saw some example of express js with react js, but it was not clear and i'm new to that as well).

**I just need to find a way to authenticate an user and then serve him a fully rendered html page to view in his browser (*it sounds so easy to explain it this way*)** Any help or direction / suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: `the problem is that since I have put the files inside a static folder (configured in startup) users can easily change the URL and access other files present there` You said user can easily access other files stored in that folder, how does user know these files info on your web server, such as file name, file extension name etc?

Comment: Because, the converted pages ( produced by Potree converter) has the project file names. Any user who has access the project can easily guess the model names present inside.. Let say, we have a Model, "BuildingABC" then the converted html page will be "BuildingABC.html" and for each building, we follow a set of ISO standard names.. So, it is easy to guess for people working on the buildings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried different methods to solve this issue. Finally, i have arrived at a solution. (May be it is not the best but could be helpful to someone who also has similar issue).

**WORK FLOW:**
Now, we receive several built webpages from our external sub contractors every week. Our subcontractors use Potree Converter to convert their point cloud data to web pages (which has several html, js, css) zipped into files of about 2-3 GB (because of the size of the point cloud data). It is not possible to download all files at one go to the client browser. This is handled by potree web page itself. Based on user browsing, the html page fetches portion of the data and sends frequently. However, we don't have to worry about it as it is completely managed by Potree dev team ( Thanks to Institute of Computer Graphics and Algorithms, TU Wien)

So, we cannot do much with the html site we receive from our sub contractors. Our work is to host and provide secure access to stake holders.

**APPLICATIONS:**
Initially I had developed two applications and also had a converted html page from Potree converter.

1. React JS web app : For working as a front end (**Let's call App 1**)
2. Dot net core 3.1 backend: For handling API requests. (**Let's call App 2**)

This project is hosted in IIS. So, I created a new site (running on a different port behind a firewall and not exposed to external parties). Let's call this as **Target Site**

**Reverse proxy setup through IIS**

1. We set up a reverse proxy in IIS (through ARR) for all incoming requests.
2. IIS will filter the incoming URL which has a particular string in the URL. (For example, **/5506f977-7463-4f85-86ff-7ca63bac34fa/** , lets say **url_guid**).
3. URL Rewrite will change this and direct to the target site (running on different port behind firewall)

**Target Files setup **

4. Each time we receive new target pages (converted zip files) from sub contractors, we take the index.html file, rename it with GUID (target_file_GUID), add a  tag to the header to include the url_guid and place it in a common directory.
5. We add the target_file_GUID to a column our Mysql database table which also has a column to store the actual name of the file.

**Solution**

1. From App 1, we send requests to App 2 (with JWT authentication in headers and the required HTML file(or the point cloud model)).
2. After validating, we fetch the guid name of the corresponding html file from the MYSQL
3. This particular file is then fetched from the common directory and sent to the browser.
4. At this point, the browser URL still doesn't change and contains the same URL used to reach the API controller.
5. When the Html file is loaded, it also tries to load the required JS, CSS files mentioned in the html. The trick happens here. Since we have specified  tag, new url request is sent to the server which is intercepted by the IIS and rewritten to internal server. (At this point, the URL in the client browser still doesn't change because of the server Rewrite).
6. Client broser receives the JS, CSS files (but still the URL in the client browser and also the request headers doesn't show actual URL).

**Conclusion**
I apologize for writing a long response and no much code. The whole setup and idea took more time to conceive (still there might be better way to handle it. I don't know).

The key achievements here are

1. authorize users before directing them to different URL.
2. URL Rewrite doesn't show the original url to the client browser
3. Original target site is still protected behind the firewall
4. the original file name of the html is replaced with GUID (which is hard to guess for the user) and this html guid name is changed repeatedly through a windows service console application every week. (Let's say we have 1000 files in total. The names change every week to keep it secure and confident).
5. Users cannot direclty access the html file (even if he knows the name of the file. Because this is served only through the App 2 after authentication)

More or less, we feel that at this point this is secure enough to proceed further. If someone else is facing similar issue and has achieved different solution, please do share.